# Move a Bitnami WordPress project from one computer to another Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, bitnami

I have a local WordPress project running on the Bitnami WordPress stack. Now I want to shift this project to another computer. So how do I run this project to another computer without installing Bitnami again?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XAMPP as an alternative to Bitnami.